# MySQL package does not want to install

Tags: linux, installation, debian, mysql, packages

I am trying to install the packages `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` on Debian Jessie but I get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client is already the newest version.
mysql-server is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried various solutions found on different forums but none of them work.

Such as `apt-get -f autoremove`

What is the cause of this problem and how can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

The command `apt-get -f install` outputs this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  mariadb-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,620 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 51712 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.47-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.47-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.47-0+deb8u1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**EDIT 2**

Removing the suggested file `/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag` and then running `apt-get -f autoremove` again gives me the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  mariadb-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.47-0+deb8u1) ...
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you try apt-get -f install ? Post the full output

Comment: apt-get -f install says : If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again. But you don mention doing so.

Comment: oh, I missed that. let me try that

Comment: @GertPellin please see edit. I still get errors

Comment: @vaid, just guessing, but try to install mysql-5.5 after manually removing mariadb-common. mysql-5.5 includes mysql-server, -client and everything else you need to use it, could be the solution. You should also do a bugreport at debian.

Comment: @GertPellin strangely, even though I know I installed `MariaDB`, I can't find any related packages when running the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`. I tried your suggestion by installing `mysql-5.5` and it worked. How do I test if it REALLY works?

Comment: btw, `mysql-server`, `-client` and everything else did not get installed.

Comment: What do you mean with How do I test if it really works???

Comment: @GertPellin I was thinking to maybe see if somehow it was possible to run a command which does some kind of test or something.

Comment: I didn't have time to fiddle around with `mysql` so I installed `mariadb` instead. So I am running `mariadb` now.

Answer (score 0):

I've met this error when I need to install 5.7 after MariaDB. `erase` and `autoremove` didn't help.

**WARNING**: this command **will DESTROY** your data! Do not run it if you need the data. I did not need it (a fresh server) so I just `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*`, it helped immediately.

Answer (score -1):

> If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
>   /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.

As is understand from your terminal output, your system already has mysql-server installed with a newer version as you try to install.

You can check it with a command which show you installed packages (with version and other details):

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql-server
```

Then you can be sure if you have mysqlserver, and which version you have. So you can stay with the installed version or if you want to force the installation of the older package, the terminal output ask you for deleting a file which is: /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
```

Please be carfull with the rm command, (particulary with sudo)
after this deletion, your reinstallation sould work.

Comment: mysql-server 10 does not exist, he is installing the newest version. He also did do what you suggest in edit 2

Comment: You are approx right, last stable version is 5.7.11 according to wikipedia, so we are not at the number 10. So its's strange that apt-get sent this message:

Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.5.

I would advise him to reconfigure the mysql-server package:

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

And if it still not work, purge all the mysql related package and try a new install

Comment: mysql-server 10 is a MariaDB